# Receiving list index out of range error while looping through multiple words in PyTrends?

Tags: python, list, loops, google-trends

I am having some trouble iterating through Google trends data using the pseudo google trends API PyTrends. When I use the google trends website it is fine with me using multiple words together so long as I use the "+" symbol in between words. For example: "a-kasse+akasse+arbejdsformidling+arbejdsformidlinger+dagpenge+dagpengeperiode". When I use a single word in my code, the program works as expected. But when I use multiple words concatenated it breaks.

When I use the following function, it throws a list index out of range error:

```
def my_funct(Keyword, Dates, Country, Col_name):
 
    KEYWORDS=[Keyword] 

    KEYWORDS_CODES=[pytrend.suggestions(keyword=i)[0] for i in KEYWORDS] 

    df_CODES= pd.DataFrame(KEYWORDS_CODES)

    EXACT_KEYWORDS=df_CODES['mid'].to_list()

    DATE_INTERVAL= Dates
    COUNTRY=[Country] #Use this link for iso country code
    CATEGORY=0 # Use this link to select categories
    SEARCH_TYPE='' #default is 'web searches',others include 'images','news','youtube','froogle' (google shopping)


    Individual_EXACT_KEYWORD = list(zip(*[iter(EXACT_KEYWORDS)]*1))
    Individual_EXACT_KEYWORD = [list(x) for x in Individual_EXACT_KEYWORD]
    dicti = {}
    i = 1

    for Country in COUNTRY:
        for keyword in Individual_EXACT_KEYWORD:
            try:
                pytrend.build_payload(kw_list=keyword, 
                                      timeframe = DATE_INTERVAL,
                                      geo = Country, 
                                      cat = CATEGORY,
                                      gprop = SEARCH_TYPE) 
                dicti[i] = pytrend.interest_over_time()
                i+=1
                time.sleep(9)
                print(dicti)
                
            except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
                    print("Timeout occured")
        
    df_trends = pd.concat(dicti, axis=1)


    df_trends.columns = df_trends.columns.droplevel(0) #drop outside header
    df_trends = df_trends.drop('isPartial', axis = 1) #drop "isPartial"
    df_trends.reset_index(level=0,inplace=True) #reset_index
    df_trends.columns=['date', Col_name] #change column names
  

    return df_trends
```

I execute that function through another function as follows:

```
df_merged3 = excelConcatFunct("a-kasse+akasse+arbejdsformidling+arbejdsformidlinger+dagpenge+dagpengeperiode", 'DK', 'DANISH search terms')
```

And here is how that function works:

```
def excelConcatFunct(Word, Country_code, Col_name):

# generic plug-n-chug data
x1 = my_funct(Word, '2004-01-04 2009-01-04', Country_code, Col_name)
x2 = my_funct(Word, '2009-01-05 2014-01-05', Country_code, Col_name)
x3 = my_funct(Word, '2014-01-06 2019-01-06', Country_code, Col_name)              
x4 = my_funct(Word, '2019-01-07 {0}'.format(Today), Country_code, Col_name)      

# generic plug-n-chug data
df1 = pd.DataFrame(x1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(x2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(x3)
df4 = pd.DataFrame(x4)

# Creates an empty dataframe to add to merged df for column spacing
df0 = pd.DataFrame()
df0[''] = ''

# this concats the df horizontally
df_merged = pd.concat([df1, df0, df2, df0, df3, df0, df4], axis=1)
df_merged.reset_index(inplace=True)
# This removes the dangling last column that said "Unamed:0"
df_merged = df_merged.loc[:, ~df_merged.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]
# This removes the dangling first index column
df_merged = df_merged.loc[:, ~df_merged.columns.str.contains('^index')]

# returns the merged dataframe 
return df_merged
```

And here is the error message I am getting:

```
  File "C:\Users\JohnReese\Desktop\G_Trends\G_Trender.py", line 111, in <module>
    df_merged3 = excelConcatFunct("a-kasse+akasse+arbejdsformidling+arbejdsformidlinger+dagpenge+dagpengeperiode", 'DK', 'DANISH search terms')

  File "C:\Users\JohnReese\Desktop\G_Trends\G_Trender.py", line 83, in excelConcatFunct
    x1 = my_funct(Word, '2004-01-04 2009-01-04', Country_code, Col_name)

  File "C:\Users\JohnReese\Desktop\G_Trends\G_Trender.py", line 31, in my_funct
    KEYWORDS_CODES=[pytrend.suggestions(keyword=i)[0] for i in KEYWORDS]

  File "C:\Users\JohnReese\Desktop\G_Trends\G_Trender.py", line 31, in <listcomp>
    KEYWORDS_CODES=[pytrend.suggestions(keyword=i)[0] for i in KEYWORDS]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Please help. Any and all help is welcomed.

Thank you!

Comment: Your code assumes that `pytrend.suggestions(keyword=i)` always returns at least one item. By accessing the returned value at `[0]` without checking if there are items in the list, you open yourself up to that error. Is the issue that that function is always supposed to be returning something but it's not, or you're just not guarding against that scenario?

Comment: @RandomDavis Thanks! Should I remove that line entirely? or create an if-statment or rewrite it as: KEYWORDS_CODES = [pytrend.suggestions(keyword=i)?

Comment: I don't know what that rewrite is supposed to do, it seems incomplete. Also, removing that entire line would just break things I'd think, since you still need `KEYWORDS_CODES` later. I don't know what it means to get "suggestions" for multiple keywords, or what you're using the suggestions for, so I can't really say what you should do instead. Maybe you should be looking up each keyword individually rather than all at once as a concatenated string joined by `+`? Just a wild guess though.

Comment: @RandomDavis Thanks. Sorta new to Python. Was using this for a reference: https://towardsdatascience.com/a-very-precise-fast-way-to-pull-google-trends-data-automatically-4c3c431960aa?gi=cbbd36f67452. Which is very similar to the code above, but not using multiple words. How could I do to still get PyTrends in absolute values while joining each of those words individually?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'd try having the line `KEYWORDS=[Keyword]` be replaced with one that splits `Keyword` on `'+'` first, and then see how that works.

Comment: @RandomDavis Sorry late reply, tried this, replaced KEYWORDS = [Keyword] with  
    KEYWORDS= Keyword.split('+'), and am still getting list index out of range. I think it has something to do with getting the 'mid'.